# dynamically create link tables and rename them in access 2007/2003 with c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, oledb

I'm looking to be able to dynamically create linked tables with C# in an accdb/mdb existing file. Is this possible? The idea would be for every linked table ALREADY in a given access database dynamically create a new linked table and then the second part of the problem would be to then rename name this newly created table to the pre existing table.

If its not already clear there is a migration going on from one database to another so every pre existing table has an equivalent table in the new database but they need to have the same name in the Access database in order for the queries to work etc.

Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**

I have created a test database that contains one linked table to an ODBC database. I have also created a simple query that just counts the rows. My C# code runs the query first and then *attempts* to change the connection string with the code:

```
    var dbe = new DBEngine();
    Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\x339\Documents\Test.accdb");
    foreach (TableDef tbd in db.TableDefs)
    {
        if (tbd.Connect.Length > 5)
        {
            if (tbd.Connect.Substring(0, 5).Equals("ODBC;"))
            {
                tbd.Connect = tbd.Connect.Replace("ODBC;DSN=ILACFEUC;UID=cloaseuc;DBQ=ILACFEUC;DBQ=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=F;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=F;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=0;MLD=0;ODA=F;;TABLE=CLOASEUCDBA.T_BASIC_POLICY", "ODBC;DSN=ILACFEUC;UID=cloaseuc;DBQ=ILACFEUC;DBQ=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=F;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=F;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=0;MLD=0;ODA=F;;TABLE=CLOASEUCDBA.T_BILLING_INFORMATION");
                tbd.RefreshLink();
            }
        }
    }
```

however it is not working. If I open the database up in access the connection string is unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really just want to change the external database to which the existing linked tables are connected. In that case you could do it in C# like this:

```csharp
// This code requires the following COM reference in your project:
//
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// and the declaration
//
//     using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
//
// at the top of the class file

var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\FrontEnd.accdb");
foreach (TableDef tbd in db.TableDefs)
{
    if (tbd.Connect.Length > 10)
    {
        if (tbd.Connect.Substring(0, 10).Equals(";DATABASE="))
        {
            tbd.Connect = tbd.Connect.Replace("oldBackEnd.accdb", "newBackEnd.accdb");
            tbd.RefreshLink();
        }
    }
}
db.Close();
```

Comment: what is the reference within the code? I've added the COM reference. Also I see that the Replace() is taking accdb files. These linked tables are linked ODBC oracle tables migrating to ODBC sql server tables. Is this still applicable?

Comment: @Andy For ODBC linked tables the principle is the same but the `.Connect` properties will look different (they will start with `ODBC;` instead of `;DATABASE=`).

Comment: Please check the edit, I think I'm close to resolving the issue.